# How do I set Open Graph actions to change spelling between US and UK English?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I am creating an app with an Open Graph Action ('favourite') that has different spellings in the US and UK. I want to ensure that when a user shares a story to their timeline the correct spelling is shared. Facebook says that action translations happen automatically, though as they are both English I don't know if Facebook treats them different languages.

The Internationalisation documentation doesn't offer any answers to this specific question - does any one have any experience of this / know if spelling change will happen?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create the Open Graph Action with US spelling
2. Add the language *English (UK)* on the Localization page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP-ID]/localize
3. "Translate" the phrases from US English to UK English:     http://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/browse.php?app=[APP-ID]